# Compare a current user against a list of employees logged into computers Perl, CGI

Tags: html, sql, perl, cgi

Not sure I am doing this correctly as it doesn't appear to be working.

Is this the correct way to declare my users, and is the If statement correctly formated?

At the top I have declared:

```
my $las = 'jpietrza hpietrza oszones';
```

These are employees we are checking against current users.

Further down in the code, I want to change the text color that is printed if the user is in the list vs. someone else.

```
while ( $sth->fetch() ) {

    next unless defined $currentuser;

    $lastlogin =~ s/ .*$//;
    $host_name =~ s/1408//;

    foreach ( @las ) {

        if ( $currentuser eq "$_" ) {
            $lacolor = "black";
            last;
        }
        else {
            $lacolor = "red";
        }
    }

    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>$host_name</td>";
    print "<td><font color=\"$lacolor\">System In-Use (User Undisclosed)</font></td><td>&nbsp;</td>";
}
```

Comment: What is the question? See also: [ask]

Comment: *Is this the correct way to declare my users?* Probably not. You most likely want an array or a hash instead. *Is the If statement correctly formated?* There don't appear to be any syntax errors, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Judging by the way you use `$las` and `@las` in a way that seems to be interchangeable, I suspect you would learn a lot if you added `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe there was nothing wrong with the `if` statement, but the whole 9 lines of code can be condensed to 1 very readable line:

`$lacolor = any { /^$currentuser$/ } @las ? "black" : "red";`

please

```
use List::Util qw/any/;

while($sth->fetch()) {

    # $currentuser is assigned between the 'while' and this 'next' statement ?
    # if not, then outside the loop and do not loop at all unless defined

    next unless defined $currentuser;

    $lastlogin=~s/ .*$//;
    $host_name=~s/1408//;

    $lacolor = any { /^$currentuser$/ } @las ? "black" : "red";

    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>$host_name</td>";
    print "<td><font color=\"$lacolor\">System In-Use (User Undisclosed)</font></td><td>&nbsp;</td>";
}
```

please, also `use strict;` and `use warnings;`

Comment: I think this is a case where a simple hash beats an array and `any()` cleverness :-)

Comment: Also, if you look at [this user's previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718893/want-to-hide-cgi-rendered-html-text-for-hostname-when-username-text-column-is-em), you'll see that `$currentuser` is set up using `bind_columns` (so it's changed every time `fetch()` is called). And your confusion neatly illustrates why that's such a bad idea.

Comment: Is there a method to exclude results and not print them if they are not members of the array @las ?

Comment: sure... when you want the print statements conditional, wrap those inside an `if` statement like `if (any { /^$currentuser$/ } @las) { print ... }`

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to put the array together correctly:

```
my @las = qw( 
jpietrza
hpietrza
oszones

);
```

instead of:

```
my $las='
jpietrza
hpietrza
oszones
';
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as I think you have worked out now, the scalar variable `$las` and the array `@las` are completely different. As you've seen, you should declare and initialise your array like this:

```
my @las = qw(
  jpietrza
  hpietrza
  oszones
);
```

Actually, I suspect this all gets easier if you store this in a hash, not an array;

```
my %las = map { $_ => 1 } qw(jpietrza hpietrza oszones);
```

Then your check just becomes:

```
my $lacolour = $las{$currentuser} ? 'black' : 'red';
```

A few more points:

- Please add `use strict` and `use warnings`. And understand and fix the problems they reveal.
- The quotes are unnecessary in `if ($currentuser eq "$_")`.
- Using a [templating system](https://metacpan.org/release/Template-Toolkit) to create the output will make your life a lot easier.

**Update:** Oh, and one I forgot earlier. It's 2017. No-one has used the `font` element in HTML for fifteen years. Take a look at [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).

Comment: The CSS is a good point, I often inherit code that has been on server projects for some time.